# Computer sleep and wake up announcement on a network

Tags: networking, packet

I wonder if there's some sort of network packet that announces a computer going to sleep or waking up again.

If not, can you think of reasons why this would be a bad idea?

Answer (score 3):

Try looking into [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol). There might be a setting for that already.

Comment: Good point! I'll have a look!

Answer (score 2):

[Wake-on-LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) is an Ethernet computer networking standard that allows a computer to be turned on or woken up by a network message.

You can intercept sleep and wakeup events. See the following:
[A useful utility - run a program before standby](http://forum.pocketables.net/showthread.php?t=4773)
[WMI : Win32_PowerManagementEvent Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394362%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This is why I am asking - I'm thinking about a way to inform a server (all devices for that matter) that a device has woken up. Otherwise a device might not notice. This could come in handy when it comes to waking up computers that don't support 'wake on unicast' etc.

Comment: OK : added some more stuff.